# java bytecode - representation of types smaller than int

Tags: java, jvm, bytecode

In one of the projects at my university I am working directly with Java bytecode.

After browsing the list of instructions available for the JVM (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_bytecode_instruction_listings) I saw that there is no such thing as `[b|c|s]store,` only `istore` for storing integers in a local variable. Does it mean that if in my program I write:

```
short a;
int b;
```

I am not saving any memory, because every local variable entry occupies 4 bytes?

I was always under the impression that using `short` or `byte` types will save some memory at runtime.

Comment: That sounds correct. You still get the savings using `byte[]`s, however.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

This is explained in section [2.11.1 of the JVMS](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jvms/se7/html/jvms-2.html#jvms-2.11.1):

> Note that most instructions *[...]* do not have forms for the integral types `byte`, `char`, and `short`. None have forms for the `boolean` type. A compiler encodes loads of literal values of types `byte` and `short` using Java Virtual Machine instructions that sign-extend those values to values of type `int` at compile-time or run-time. *[...]* Thus, most operations on values of actual types `boolean`, `byte`, `char`, and `short` are correctly performed by instructions operating on values of computational type `int`.

It is justified thus:

> Given the Java Virtual Machine's one-byte opcode size, encoding types into opcodes places pressure on the design of its instruction set. If each typed instruction supported all of the Java Virtual Machine's run-time data types, there would be more instructions than could be represented in a byte. Instead, the instruction set of the Java Virtual Machine provides a reduced level of type support for certain operations. In other words, the instruction set is intentionally not orthogonal. Separate instructions can be used to convert between unsupported and supported data types as necessary.

However, whilst this applies to load/store of stack variables, it doesn't apply to load/store into primitive arrays; there are opcodes for all primitive types.

Answer (score 3):

You are not saving any memory using a local `int` vs `long` as these are likely to be in 64-bit registers.  Note: how the byte code is laid out and how the code is actually run is not the same.

Saving two bytes is not important on any new hardware.  The value of 2 bytes is less than 1/1000 the time it takes you to blink even if you are on minimum wage.

Comment: I know that I will not save any significant memory, I was just curious about this case.

Comment: Although if you have billions of 2-bytes savings, it might get more interesting... But I agree, usually it doesn't make sense to to waste your time thinking about a few bytes on modern systems.

Comment: Yes but in an embedded environment, those bytes can/will add up, making this important.

Comment: @SnakeDoc They can add up if you have enough of them in any system.  Even in embedded systems using a 16-bit register instead of a 32-bit one is unlikely to make much difference.

Comment: @PeterLawrey Right, in embedded you're likely more worried about excessive object instanciations instead of primatives, When your working with a system that has only 128MB of RAM available between the OS and any user software, then this sort of stuff would be more up front in your thinking instead of normal desktop development where memory consumption likely doesn't even cross your mind (unless you run into significant performance bottlenecks). Different focuses.