# Why jvm expands byte & short to int before pushing on stack?

Tags: java, jvm, byte, bytecode, short

java code : ,

```
byte a_b = 12;
short c_d = 14
```

replaces in bytecodes with

```
bipush  12 // expands byte1 (a byte type) to an int and pushes it onto the stack
sipush   14 // expands byte1, byte2 (a short type) to an int and pushes it onto the stack
```

Why jvm does that expansion, and not use byte & short ?

Also when i open bytecode of my file

***EDIT* : short var = 14 is replaced by bipush 14 rather than sipush 14**

Is my understanding is not clear or is there a bug ?

[image]

I am using following version

```
java version "1.6.0_26"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.6.0_26-b03)
Java HotSpot(TM) Client VM (build 20.1-b02, mixed mode, sharing)
```

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/a/17094810/724361 .

Comment: Mainly because that's the way they defined it, and there's no compelling need to have it defined differently.  (The stack is conceptually only incremented/decremented in 4-byte increments, though a little tap-dance obviously must occur in 8-byte JVMs.)

Comment: And a bipush is 2 bytes long, while a sipush is 3 bytes long.  Why use the longer instruction when the shorter works just as well?

Comment: @HotLicks see the snap added from following link http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jvms/se7/html/jvms-2.html#jvms-2.6.2

Comment: You mean "At any point in time, an operand stack has an associated depth, where a value of type long or double contributes two units to the depth and a value of any other type contributes one unit. "?

Comment: (The fact of the matter is that the Java designers sort of screwed up (if you ignore that Java was originally only for set-top boxes).  They should have made the stack have "conceptual" entries that could contain any size, but chose instead to "hard-wire" it to 4-byte entries.  This causes a number of distortions of the architecture.)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Because (conceptually) the smallest unit of data on the JVM stack is 32 bits.  So there is no way to increase the size of the stack with just 8 bits.

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jvms/se7/html/jvms-2.html#jvms-2.6.2

> At any point in time, an operand stack has an associated depth, where
>   a value of type long or double contributes two units to the depth and
>   a value of any other type contributes one unit.

Comment: I think you mean decrease ;-) Also you could only write 8 bit of data into a 32 bit stackframe. I just would be a waste of space. I think the real reason is found in the answer @TheTerribleSwiftTomato has linked in the comments.

Comment: @stonedsquirrel - They *do* write the 8 bits of data into the 32-bit stack frame.  And then they sign-extend into the rest of the frame.

Comment: @HotLicks Of course. That you not only could do it but have to with a fixed stack frame size skipped my mind ;-) Thanks!